# HTML Canvas - change text dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to change the text on my html canvas while I type inside an input text field.

I can add the text however, if I delete and type again the new text is added on the top of the old one.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bm7jv7bk/1/)

```
document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var stringTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
    console.log(stringTitle);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
    var text_title = stringTitle;
    ctx.fillText(stringTitle, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
    });
```

Comment: You need to clear your canvas before showing text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. You just clear the canvas every time it's updated.

```
document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var stringTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
    console.log(stringTitle);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0e70d1';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
    var text_title = stringTitle;
    ctx.fillText(stringTitle, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
    });
```

**UPDATE**

In case you only want to update the area where the text is, you can do just that,

```
ctx.fillRect(0, 130, canvas.width, 70);
```

Another approach would be, keeping track of the text as well as other objects in the canvas and refreshing the entire canvas. This is not as memory intensive as you'd think. If you want, you could also reset the canvas only when the text has been deleted (completely or partially), by comparing the previous string with new one.

Comment: This works however, if I have something else on the canvas it will clear everything else is on there

Comment: In that case you only clear the area where the text is.
I'll update the answer, just a moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the state of the canvas, update the content, then restore it via:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#0e70d1';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var stringTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
    var text_title = stringTitle;
    ctx.fillText(stringTitle, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
    ctx.restore();
});
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="300" id="canvas">Sorry, no canvas available</canvas>
<input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Your Title" />
</br>
```

Comment: why `save()` and `restore()` ?

Comment: @Kaiido - It's something I've used for a while, mostly with canvas transformations, but I've found it works equally well with simple redraws.

Comment: Actually it will eventually only save your `fillStyle` and `font` properties (not even sure about it) and are quite consumptive methods, you should avoid if you're not dealing with transformations

Comment: @Kaiido In this case, these are very necessary, because once the `fillstyle` gets changed to `#fff` the `fillRect`, in the next call, would fill the canvas with white, which is not something we want. `save` and `restore` are very convenient when using transformations.

Comment: @j08691. `context.save` & `context.restore` will save and restore the entire context state (eg all stylings, transformations, composite settings, etc). Since .save & .restore are modestly expensive you might instead begin with `var previousFill=ctx.fillStyle` and end by resetting just the fillStyle with `ctx.fillStyle=previousFill`. :-)

Comment: @ShashwatBlack I think it's a better practice to just reset the `fillStyle` to the color you want every time you draw something, it will avoid some other external errors

Comment: I agree with you. In this case it *is* an overkill. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try replace last few line with this

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#0e70d1';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillText(stringTitle, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
```

by canvas limitation, you must redraw whole canvas in order to update its content

Answer (score 0):

I would add your text to an array and then clear the canvas after every time you type and redraw all the text.

As the letter are different widths and so are spaces and backspaces you can't be certain you will exactly clear the letter you want to delete.

Comment: what about [`ctx.measureText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText)