# Change text in canvas object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, canvas

In below example, lets say json.mes is the received message from Ajax; A button is designed which must display the message in a canvas box. I have tried to read the message using getElementById (as below); however, it does not work. Any solution?

```
<div> <button id="submit"  type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;">Populate</button></div>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas3");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
ctx.fillStyle = "#dbbd7a";

ctx.font = "10px Comic Sans MS";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("picoutput0"), 74, 74);
</script>

<script>
...
 $("#submit").click(function(e) {
...
var text0=json.mes
$('#picoutput0').html(text0);
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("picoutput0").innerHTML`, but you'd be better just make `text0` available to your canvas script (it currently seems to be in global scope already) and directly call `ctx.fillText(text0, x, y)`

Comment: @Kaiido I have tried that; it does not work. Also the .innerHTML does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882814/html-canvas-change-text-dynamically

Comment: @subbu1191 kind of similar but not exactly; I provided a non-working example: https://jsfiddle.net/06wwx038

Comment: `document.getElementById("picoutput0")` returns an element, **not** the text that it contains.. You'll want to extract the text before you can draw it.

Comment: @enhzflep and what is your suggestion to do so?

Comment: try this document.getElementById('picoutput0').textContent

Comment: @Amal not working. I have already tested in the given jsfiddle example.

Comment: @salehinejad https://jsfiddle.net/06wwx038/3/

Comment: @Amal it works there for the case without Ajax (I forgot the #); I wonder why it does not work for Ajax and Button problem. mentioned in the question?

Comment: @salehinejad - head over to MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) and read the docs for the type of element that contains the text, so that you have some kind of a clue what you're doing, which apparently, is not the case presently. You're mixing jQuery and vanilla javascript - your code is a cacophony of copy and paste. Would you jump into deep water without knowing what you were doing and hope to get swimming directions that would prevent your from drowning? It seems you're trying to code in a similar manner. Learn to use your debugger too, it will only help you!

Comment: @enhzflep this is not how you can encourage someone who is learning new stuff.

Comment: @salehinejad Does this help you http://jsfiddle.net/hh11bmuq/

Comment: @salehinejad - I learned to program without the net - it just didn't exist then. We learned by thinking, reading and following examples. I'm sorry if you find my comments uncomfortably harsh. It seems that so many today are unprepared to receive what others intend to be a reality-check. I suggested you use MDN and implored you to use a debugger. If you were already doing both, your question wouldn't be here. Well done for trying, it's a good step along the way to trying harder. Also, read the [help], particularly the part that speaks of an [mcve]. You will be better for it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#0e70d1';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var stringTitle = document.getElementById('title').textContent;
console.log(stringTitle);
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText(stringTitle, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hh11bmuq/3/)